# How to run laravel program at CLI?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to run laravel program at CLI, but I don't know how to write the command.
I try to like this `/laravel/index.php /controller/method`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You can't do that. If you want to create a custom command for console read the doc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can refer this link for commands : https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan

using artisan you can create your command as well as controller and model for your application

Answer (score 2):

laravel artisan command provides functionality for CLI. you can use predefined command and also create your own command as per your requirements, [Official documents](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/artisan).

Answer (score 0):

Go to your laravel working folder using CLI

```
cd your_larave_folder_name
```

Then run this command

```
php -S localhost:8888 -t public
```

This will run your application at port 8888.To access your views using a browser.

```
localhost:8888/name_of_your_view
```

You can use any port number other than 8888, also you must run CLI with administrative privileges.